# How to override to_json for ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is the following code for lib/error.rb module:

```
  class ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
    def to_json
      { result_code: 5 }
    end
  end
```

And the following code to catch exception:

```
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  render json: e
end
```

But I've got an empty hash as the result. How can I fix it?

Comment: what's wrong? Why is my wish bad?

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish with that approach. Why not try to capture the error in your base api controller (if you have one )

```
 class BaseApiController < ActionController::Base

      rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  do |e|
          render :json => {"ErrorType" => "Record Not Found", "message" => e.message},
       :code => :bad_request
      end

 end
```